# Multiple inner assignments - how it works?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, micro-optimization

I'm trying to do a "1-liner" for fun purposes and for some reason i can't make the code work properly. Note: that's C, not C++, however the issue persists in both.

The "unfolded" version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double iter = 1;
    double res = 0;
    double elem = 0;
    double fib_c = 1;
    double fib_p = 1;
    double power = 4;
    double fact = 1;

    while (iter < 15) {
        fib_c += fib_p; //fibonacci current
        fib_p = fib_c - fib_p; //fibonacci previous
        fact *= iter; //factorial
        power *= 4; //power of 4
        elem = (fib_c * power * sqrt(iter+1)) / fact; //element of series
        res += elem; //series

        printf("----\nelem = %2.3f\nres = %2.3f\n", elem, res);

        iter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's a series (i don't know the mathematical term for it in english) and here the `elem`ent goes up from 45 to 1264 and then goes back down to 47.

Here's the "wrapped" version i'm trying to make work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double iter = 1;
    double res = 0;
    double elem = 0;
    double fib_c = 1;
    double fib_p = 1;
    double power = 4;
    double fact = 1;

    while (iter < 15) {
        res += (elem = (fib_c += ((fib_p = fib_c - fib_p)) * (power*=4) * sqrt(iter+1)) / (fact*=iter));

        printf("----\nelem = %2.3f\nres = %2.3f\n", elem, res);

        iter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the `elem`ent goes beyond integer in less than 5 iterations. So obviously, something is wrong. But what?

By the way, if i print out each value (`fib_c`, `power`, `fact`) each iteration, i will see the correct values (current fibonacci number, power of 4, ongoing factorial, accordingly). So i made a guess that there is something weird happening "behind the scenes" and i don't know how to manage it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't write code like that, it is unmaintainable and the side benefit is weird undefined behavior won't happen. A quick look says you are modifying `fib_c` and reading it within the same sequence point which is classical C undefined behavior. See [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/1708801).

Comment: As i said, "for fun purposes". Nobody's going to maintain the code after me.

Comment: @ohyou Undefined behavior is not fun, so Shafik's point stands ;)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I see no UB there under either version of the sequencing wording.

Comment: @T.C. note I did use the term sequence point, so in C and pre C++11 reading other than to determine the new value and modifying the same variable within the same sequence point is UB. In C++11 and C11(*although C11 does retain the sequence point terminology and so either analysis should have the same result*) and as far as I can tell this is still UB in C++11.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour it *is* reading fib_c to determine the value to be stored into it.

Comment: @T.C. yes but there is an assignment to `fib_p` that intervenes which I believe changes the analysis since `fib_c` has to be read to assign the value to that.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour How does that change the analysis? Both reads of `fib_c` (one from `+=` and one from  `fib_p = fib_c - fib_p`) occur as part of the computation of the value to be assigned to `fib_c`. That the second read also occurs as part of the computation of the value to be assigned to `fib_p` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(fib_c += ((fib_p = fib_c - fib_p))
```

is not the same as

```
fib_c += fib_p; //fibonacci current
fib_p = fib_c - fib_p; //fibonacci previous
```

It is the same as

```
fib_p = fib_c - fib_p; //fibonacci previous
fib_c += fib_p; //fibonacci current
```

Comment: Wow thanks for that, i missed that somehow. The correct line (in terms of algorithm) would be `(fib_p = (fib_c += fib_p) - fib_p)` if somebody is interested.

Comment: "you are using fib_c on both sides of the += operator" are you seriously claiming that `i += i;` is UB?

Comment: @T.C., no. I am claiming `i += (i + 10);` is UB. That's a hunch. I might be mistaken.

Comment: That expands into `i = i + (i + 10);`. How is that UB?

Comment: @T.C., After reading more on the sequence points and what constitutes UB, I concluded that my hunch is not right.